# Why observables are used in angular 2

Tags: angular, service, angular2-observables

When i am writing services in angular,i repeatedly seen a word called 'Observable'.
My Interface,

```
 export interface IDetails{
              custominfo:string;
    }
```

My Service,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { IDetails } from './data';

@Injectable()
export class GetAllList {
    id =  this.loc._id;
    private _productUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/getprofilebyid/'+this.id;

    constructor(private _http: Http) { }
    getList(): Observable<IDetails[]> {
        return this._http.get(this._productUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => {  return <IDetails[]> response.json().data; 
        });

    }
}
```

I have 2 doubts,

1)Why all my variables are which i get as a result of http call is declared in an file called 'interface'.

2)What is the use of word 'Observable' in my code.

Can anyone please help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observable is a powerful alternative to Promise. 
You can think of it as an event stream. Therefore whenever an event occurs on the observable the subscriber gets notified.

Example:

```
getList(): Observable<IDetails[]> {
        return this._http.get(this._productUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => {  return <IDetails[]> response.json().data; 
        });

    }
```

Here getList() method has a return type Observable which can be subscribed to get an array containing elements of type IDetails.

Usage:

```
export class SomeComponent {
    constructor(private getAllList:GetAllList)
    this.getAllList.getList().subscribe(
        (data)=>{
            //do something with the array containing elements of type IDetails
            console.log(data);
        }),
        (error)=>{
            // handle error
            console.log(error);
        }),
        ()=>{
           // On Compete
           console.log("Subscription completed")
        })
}
```

For further reading:
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html

Comment: Hi JSNinja, why i need to declare my getcall results names iDetails?

Comment: This is the type which the Observable will provide when subscribed to. E.g Observable<string> or Observable<boolean> will provide a string, boolean respectively.

Comment: So to use observables i should declare the type?

Comment: Yes Observable require a type. You can use Observable<any> if you are not sure what is going to be returned.

Comment: So what if i dont use Observale ? Why does it require?To subscribe to the response, i must to Observable?

Comment: You can use Promises, Observable gives you much more control over the subscription. Yes you need Observable or subject so that you can subscribe to them. For further reading: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#fetch-data

Comment: Accept this as the correct answer if you think this will be useful.